# Simple, editable data in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a project that deals with execution of several models one after the other. For this, users need to upload a lot of files (mostly CSV) for each workflow, and each files has several columns.

Since understanding each file is difficult for users of our application, we want to **provide friendly names, small descriptions, help texts, etc. for each file**, and display them on our website.

These names and descriptions should be **editable by people who are not developers** (but will have access to the AWS account). So we would prefer a storage for this that provides some **convenient user-interface** for this.

In the world of AWS, what would you recommend as a storage for this use-case? Is dynamodb an overkill / inconvenient for this?

Should we have our a separate user-interface and service to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of User Interface and Storage are completely independent.

**Storage** should be selected based upon the type of data and how it will be accessed. It might be relational if you are querying and joining a lot of data, or it might be NoSQL (DynamoDB or even Amazon S3) if you need fast, predictable performance but no complex querying.

The **User Interface** should not be impacted by the choice of storage. It should present the data for viewing/editing in a way that is most convenient for users. There is no reason to have UI drive the storage choice (unless you simply want to use Google Sheets as your frontend).

Comment: My question is specifically to understand if AWS has a service that is good to store rarely-updated data and also provides a user-interface to update this data.

Comment: AWS does not offer any user-interface that is suitable for offering to end-users. The only UI is for managing your AWS resources, which is not an interface that you should present to your application users. Rarely-updated information is probably best stored in Amazon S3 (you could store the raw CSV files). There are multiple **storage classes** available, which offer a trade-off between speed of access (eg archiving) and cost.